# How to use python requests with a server that has two IP addresses

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-requests

I have a Ubuntu server that has multiple IP addresses. As an example, how do I set the correct IP address for outbound requests in a library like python requests?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if it is possible to configure the interface that the `requests` module uses?

Comment: Try the solution in this issue: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/394

Comment: If you mean binding to a source address, look at the [requests toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#sourceaddressadapter).